# Displaying and linking Foreign Key content in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, view

I am taking some online courses and in one of the exercises we are to create two tables for a blog - blog articles and blog posts - and connect them through a foreign key, then display all content from both. Comments should be linked to a specific article only, while also allowing multiple comments.

My attempt:

```
function list_articles() { 
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT blog.title, blog.content, blog.posted_by, blog.date, article_comments.comments, article_comments.comment_by
            FROM blog LEFT OUTER JOIN article_comments
            ON blog.content_id = article_comments.content_id
            WHERE blog.content != ''
            ORDER BY blog.content_id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo 
            "<h5 class='posted_by'>Posted by " . $posted_by = $row['posted_by'] . " on " . $row['date'] . "</h5>" . 
            "<h1 class='content_headers'>" . $title = $row['title'] . "</h1>" . 
            "<article>" . $content = $row['content'] . "</article>" . 
            "<div class='commented_by'>Posted by: " . $row['comment_by'] . "</div>" . 
            "<div class='comments'>Comments: " . $row['comments'] . "</div>";
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm inserting comments in the database:

```
function insert_comments($comment_by, $comments) {
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $sql =  "SELECT blog.content_id, article_comments.blog_id  
             FROM blog AS blog
             INNER JOIN article_comments AS article_comments ON article_comments.blog_id > blog.content_id";
    mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
}
```

IN PHPMyAdmin the foreign key works alright and the comments are linked to a specific article. I want to transpose this on a web page. When I insert a new article on the page it works alright, but when I try to insert a comment for that article it will not display it.

If I change `ON blog.content_id = article_comments.content_id` to `ON blog.content_id = article_comments.blog_id` (blog_id is the field name for the foreign key) - it will display all the comments for an article - but it duplicates that article for each comment associated with it. Does that make any sense? I tried explaining it as best as I can.. Please let me know if you need further clarification. Thanks

By the way, this is the statement I used to create the foreign key:

`ALTER TABLE article_comments ADD CONSTRAINT comment_blog_fk FOREIGN KEY (blog_id) REFERENCES wt.blog(content_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

**EDIT**: The result I get with `ON blog.content_id = article_comments.blog_id`

```
Article title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
--------------------------------------
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article!

-- HERE IT DUPLICATES THE ARTICLE TO INSERT A NEW COMMENT --

Article title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
--------------------------------------
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment
```

As you can see, it duplicates the article for every comment inserted. So I end up with two duplicate articles that hold different comments. If If I'll have 100 comments, the article will get replicated 100 times

The behavior I am expecting:

```
Article title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- \\ COMMENTS \\
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment
```

Comment: I see in your question only **SELECT**, but no one **INSERT**. So problem when you insert data, or when you select?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar For now, I am inserting data directly through the database interface until I figure out how to display it properly, hence no INSERT statement in my code. So, my problem lays in displaying it. In the database, comments are associated with articles correctly. The way I display them on the page seems to be the issue. More than likely there's an issue with way I am selecting either the comments or the articles.

Comment: Can you print your result from db and what you expect?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Please see my edit, does this help understand the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
        $posts = array();
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db', 'user', 'password');
        // for example all fields
        $query = $pdo->query('
            SELECT * 
              FROM blog AS blog
             INNER JOIN article_comments AS article_comments ON article_comments.blog_id = blog.content_id
        ');

        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            $idContent = $row['content_id'];

            if (!isset($posts[$idContent])) {
                $posts[$idContent] = array(
                    'posted_by' => $row['posted_by'],
                    'title' => $row['title'],
                    'content' => $row['content'],
                    'comments' => array()
                );
            }

            $posts[$idContent]['comments'][] = array(
                'comment_by' => $row['comment_by'],
                'comment' => $row['comment'],
            );

        }

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo '
                Post: ' . $row['title'] . ' . Posted by: ' . $row['posted_by'] .
                '<br/>Content: ' . $row['content'] .
                '<br/>Comments: ';
            ;

            foreach ($post['comments'] as $comment) {
                echo $comment['comment'] . '. Comment by: ' .$row['comment_by'] . '<br/>';
            }

        }
```

Comment: Tried, the articles still duplicate for each comment inserted. I think I'm gonna try and implement this in the while loop, with some adapting, your solution should work. Thanks

Comment: I think I understood what you mean. Check my answer.